# Why is readline() not getting all words from my .txt

Tags: python, file, readline

I am opening a text file, read it line by line and strip the trailing '\n' and append it to a list with code below. Some words go missing while doing this. Can anybody tell me why?

```
def compare(t, w):
    c = {}
    m = []
    for line in t:
        lines = t.readline()
        word = lines.strip()
        m.append(word)
    for x in m:
        c[x] = c.get('x', 0)
    if w in c:
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')


fin = open('words.txt')

compare(fin, 'expect')
```

Comment: quotes not needed `c.get('x', 0)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `.readline` inside of a `for line in t` loop.
Every iteration a new line will be read and in .readline the next line will be read, so you skip one line every iteration.